# Using python/numpy to create a matrix?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matrix, mean, standard-deviation

I have a basic understanding using numpy to create a matrix, but the context in which I have to create one confuses me. For example, I need to create a 2X1000 matrix with normally distributed values with mean 0 and standard deviation of 1. I'm not sure what it means to make a matrix with these conditions.

Answer (score 3):

Besides what was writeen above by CoDEmanX, From [numpy.random.normal](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) we can read about the generic Normal Distribution in numpy:
numpy.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=None)
Where:
loc is the Mean of the distribution and scale is the standard deviation (square root of variance).

```
import numpy as np 
A = np.random.normal(loc =0, scale =1, size=(2, 1000))
print(A)
```

But if these examples are confusing, then consider that

```
np.random.normal()
```

simply gives you a random number, and you can create your own custom matrix:

```
import numpy as np
A = [ [np.random.normal() for i in range(1000)]    for j in range(2) ]
A = np.array(A)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to the numpy docs, whether there are utility functions that facilitate you reaching your goal, you'll come across a normal distribution function:

```
numpy.random.standard_normal(size=None)

standard_normal(size=None)
Returns samples from a Standard Normal distribution (mean=0, stdev=1).
```

The simple average is 0, the standard deviation 1.

```
arr = numpy.random.standard_normal((2, 1000))

print(arr.mean()) # -0.027...
print(arr.std()) # 1.0272...
```

Note that it's not exactly 0 or 1.

I still recommend to read about normal distributation and [standard deviation / variance](http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation.html), eventhough numpy offers a simple solution.